# Unit testing - Unknown provider: translateFilterProvider <- translateFilter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have this unit testing that executes an error

> Unknown provider: translateFilterProvider <- translateFilter

How can I inject the $translate service?

```
import angular from 'angular'
import 'angular-mocks'

let $scope
let $compile
let htmlElement

describe('ProjectGeneralSituationForm', () => {
  beforeEach(angular.mock.module('ProjectGeneralSituationModule'))

  beforeEach(() => {
    inject((_$rootScope_, _$compile_) => {
      $scope = _$rootScope_.$new()
      $compile = _$compile_
    })
  })

  beforeEach(() => {
    $scope.project = {}
    $scope.projectTypes = {}
    $scope.projectReferences = {}
    htmlElement = $compile(`<project-general-situation-form project="project" project-types="projectTypes" project-references="projectReferences"></project-general-situation-form>`)($scope)
    $scope.$digest()
  })

  it('should be defined', () => {
    expect(htmlElement).toBeDefined()
  })
})
```

Comment: The `angularjs` tag is only meant for angular 1.x, this looks like a newer version to me. Please use the `angular` tag if it is a newer version.

Comment: @DanielWarke No it is angular 1.6.1